# PHP - Execute code from terminal, ubuntu server

Tags: php, terminal

I know that you can run php files from terminal with linux running PHP... I.e. "php script.php" ... But is there any program that allows you to directly input php into the terminal (through any intermediary program) and output the results? I.e. In terminal, testing php globals like getinfo(), etc..? Any help would be great, I'd like to test functions and commands through a sort of run-time terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`php -a` (as of PHP 5.1) should do what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Comment: If you type 'php -a' and get a response of 'Interactive Shell' followed by a 'php>' prompt, you have interactive shell available (PHP was compiled with readline support). If instead you get a response of 'Interactive mode enabled', you DO NOT have interactive shell available... [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006)

Without the shell you can try the suggested method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26822706/1815624)

Comment: @CrandellWS Thanks very much for the tip!!! I got that `Interactive mode enabled` and didn't know about that.

Comment: what about a .php file?\

Answer (score 12):

```
php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

worked for me on OSX.

Comment: A better way would be to use a shell see  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12631935/1815624) [If you type 'php -a' and get a response of 'Interactive Shell' followed by a 'php>' prompt, you have interactive shell available (PHP was compiled with readline support). If instead you get a response of 'Interactive mode enabled', you DO NOT have interactive shell available](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006) and this would be why you would use  this answer.

Answer (score -2):

You might like a program called PHP Shell Terminal: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpterm/

Comment: This is more like an SSH client written in PHP than a tool for debugging PHP.